# formula to autofill with condition and skip blank cells

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the master sheet and data sheet (more than 1 but same format)

This is the example of the data from the sheet

| Project (Column C) | Details (Column E) |
| --- | --- |
| Project A |  |
|  | Laptop |
|  | Printer |
|  | Camera |
|  |  |
| *Blank* |  |
|  | Phone |
|  | Projector |
|  |  |
| Project C |  |
|  | Implementation |
|  | Debug |
|  | Smart TV |
|  |  |

what I need to do is to copy the project and skip the second column

if the project is blank then copy all the second column

but if the next first column contains words again, then copy and skip the second column

also, skip the blank rows and the formula able to accommodate more than one data sheets

in my case, if the C Column cell is filled, then copy the cell, but if the C Column is blank, then copy the E Column until it blanks then go back to C Column

expected outcome:

| Project (Column C) |
| --- |
| Project A |
| Phone |
| Projector |
| Project C |

the formula I use right now:
=IF('Data1'!C7<>0;'Data1'!C7;'Data1'!E7)

the result from my formula:

| Project (Column C) |
| --- |
| Project A |
| Laptop |
| Printer |
| Camera |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| Phone |
| Projector |
| 0 |
| Project C |
| Implementation |
| Debug |
| Smart TV |

Note:
the data rows are not always the same number with every data sheet (i.e. data1 100 rows, data2 400 rows, so on and I need the formula to work continuously through all the sheet (i.e. after the data from data1 finished, the formula move to data2, so on)

[this is the example of C Column having data, if in this case only copy the Project A and skip the E Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v87SO.png)

[this is the example of C Column having no data, if in this case copy the E Column and when the next column C filled with data, go back and copy C column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaNsM.png)

thank you

Comment: The description and expected outcome aren't clear. What is in column E that you referenced in your formula? Please clarify your situation.

Comment: It may also help if you provide screenshots of the document itself (with fake data if necessary) so we can get a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish along with an update to your written explanation.

Comment: edited with new description and screenshot sample. Hope it can explain my problem clearly